# PostgreSql - unique rows, independent of order

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm having a bit of difficulties with the current problem

> a member has a match with another member - it can only appear once.

say we have a scheme with a table called Member and another table called Match

```
   Member
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | bob  |
| 2  | tim  |



      Match
------------------------
| memberid | requestid |(memberid is a foreign key to member same as requestid)
-------------------------
| 1        |     2     |
```

however now a request comes in from memberid 2 and it should reject it, I'm trying to find the name for that type of constraint or index. which is unique/match but doesn't matter which column.

so this should be invalid

```
      Match
------------------------
| memberid | requestid |(memberid is a foreign key to member same as requestid)
-------------------------
| 1        |     2     |
| 2        |     1     |
```

my only thoughts are adding a constraint where `memberid <> requestid`. But I thought there might a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to have only one row for pairs, then you can use a unique constraint.  The key is to build a unique index on an expression:

```
create unique index unq_matches_memberid_requestid
    on matches(least(memberid, requestid), greatest(memberid, requestid));
```

Comment: Neat! I tried messing with the `alter table add unique CONSTRAINT` syntax, and couldn't get it to work. Learned something today, thanks!

Comment: ah! it works I just don't fully understand why, how come passing in least(memberid,requestid) and greatest(memberid,requestid) suddenly makes it  a unique rows/column (the test worked out perfectly I just don't understand how that rule works)

Comment: ohh i see an expression that allows us to get both values, so the least will get one value and the greatest will give us the other which then we set a unique constraint on the expression and not the columns