# Postgresql unique constraint to allow two way combination

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a unique constraint in postgresql to join the Id's from two tables

```
TableA
IdA
1
2
3

TableB
IdB
1
2
3

TableJoin
IdA   IdB
1     1   --good
1     2   --good
1     3   --good
```

But if I want to Insert the another Id's

```
TableJoin
IdA   IdB
1     1   --good
1     2   --good
1     3   --good
2     1   --return error, because already exist 1   2 (I need save 2   1)
2     2   --good
2     3   --good
3     1   --return error, because already exist 1   3 (I need save 3   1)
```

My unique is:

ALTER TABLE TableJoin ADD CONSTRAINT "UX_Join" UNIQUE ("IdA", "IdB");

How can I insert two ways (1  2 AND 2  1) ?

Another alter unique?

Ty for help me !!!

Comment: tableJoin is actually a table - not a join?..

Comment: Yes, TableJoin is a table that have two Is's

Comment: So the row {1,2} means exactly the same thing as the row {2, 1}?

Comment: Postgres does not distinguish between order of values, 1  2 is the same that 2  1 in a unique constrain

Comment: I'm sorry?.. how is that?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSql - unique rows, independent of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320165/postgresql-unique-rows-independent-of-order)

Comment: I need the opposite of this, just I need save the 2 rows (one with 1   2 and another with 2   1) but the unique constraint  return error on insert

Comment: Please read my answer - there's example with unique key that totally allows rows (1,2) and (2,1) to be in same table

Comment: This is starting to sound like [an xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/161666).

Comment: @VaoTsun, yes, your answer allow rows (1,2) and (2,1), but don´t allow rows like (1,1)(2,2) (3,3) (4,4), etc. I need all cases (1,2)(2,1)(1,1)(2,2)

Answer (score 0):

It was answered somewhere.

basically for integers, the easiest would be creating a UK like this:

```
create unique index uk on tablejoin (least(ida,idb), greatest(ida,idb))
```

for not integers you can add to array and unnest with order in index. and even another way was with jsonb functions I believe. But greatest/least is the best option for two keys integer index...

here's a example:

```
t=# create table a (i int, e int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 27.528 ms
t=# create unique index u on a (i,e);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 25.309 ms
t=# insert into a select 1,2;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 13.972 ms
t=# insert into a select 2,1;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 8.759 ms
t=# select * from a;
 i | e
---+---
 1 | 2
 2 | 1
(2 rows)

Time: 14.570 ms
t=# create unique index u1 on a (least(i,e),greatest(i,e));
ERROR:  could not create unique index "u1"
DETAIL:  Key ((LEAST(i, e)), (GREATEST(i, e)))=(1, 2) is duplicated.
Time: 15.241 ms
```

Comment: Isn't the solution, now I have the problem whit the same values (2   2, 3   3, 4   4,....)

Comment: sorry - I must have misinterpreted your post - I thought you wanted UK so 1,2 would not allow 2,1 pair, and thus 2,2 wont allow 2,2 - yes